# ERROR: Your TexLive version is not updated enough

Tags: r, pdf, quarto, xelatex, tinytex

I would like to create a pdf document using `Quarto`. When I run the following simple code it returns the following error:

```
---
title: "Test"
format: pdf
---

Example document
```

Output error:

```
running xelatex - 1
command xelatex not found, attempting install
finding package for xelatex
ERROR: Your TexLive version is not updated enough to connect to the remote repository and download packages. Please update your installation of TexLive or TinyTex.

Underlying message: Local TeX Live (2020) is older than remote repository (2022).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

I don't understand why this error is happening. I tried using `tinytex::install_tinytex()` like described [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/install-latex.html), but after installing the error stays the same. I also updated the tlmgr which seems to work like described [here](https://yihui.org/tinytex/faq/):

```
> tinytex::tlmgr_update()
tlmgr update --all --self
```

I also tried to `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()` like this:

```
> tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()
If reinstallation fails, try install_tinytex() again. Then install the following packages:

tinytex::tlmgr_install(c("amscls", "amsfonts", "amsmath", "atbegshi", "atveryend", "auxhook", "babel", "bibtex", "bigintcalc", "bitset", "booktabs", "cm", "ctablestack", "dehyph", "dvipdfmx", "dvips", "ec", "epstopdf-pkg", "etex", "etexcmds", "etoolbox", "euenc", "everyshi", "fancyvrb", "filehook", "firstaid", "float", "fontspec", "framed", "geometry", "gettitlestring", "glyphlist", "graphics", "graphics-cfg", "graphics-def", "helvetic", "hycolor", "hyperref", "hyph-utf8", "hyphen-base", "iftex", "inconsolata", "infwarerr", "intcalc", "knuth-lib", "kpathsea", "kvdefinekeys", "kvoptions", "kvsetkeys", "l3backend", "l3kernel", "l3packages", "latex", "latex-amsmath-dev", "latex-bin", "latex-fonts", "latex-tools-dev", "latexconfig", "latexmk", "letltxmacro", "lm", "lm-math", "ltxcmds", "lua-alt-getopt", "lua-uni-algos", "luahbtex", "lualatex-math", "lualibs", "luaotfload", "luatex", "luatexbase", "mdwtools", "metafont", "mfware", "modes", "natbib", "pdfescape", "pdftex", "pdftexcmds", "plain", "psnfss", "refcount", "rerunfilecheck", "scheme-infraonly", "selnolig", "stringenc", "symbol", "tex", "tex-ini-files", "texlive-scripts", "texlive.infra", "times", "tipa", "tools", "unicode-data", "unicode-math", "uniquecounter", "url", "xcolor", "xetex", "xetexconfig", "xkeyval", "xunicode", "zapfding"))

The directory /home/quinten/.TinyTeX/texmf-local is not empty. It will be backed up to /tmp/Rtmp6FzD8d/file2890646844830b and restored later.

Found '/usr/bin/tlmgr', which indicates a LaTeX distribution may have existed in the system.
Continue the installation anyway? (Y/N) Y
tlmgr option sys_bin ~/bin
tlmgr: setting option sys_bin to /home/quinten/bin.
tlmgr: updating /home/quinten/.TinyTeX/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
tlmgr option repository 'https://mirrors.evoluso.com/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet'
tlmgr: setting default package repository to https://mirrors.evoluso.com/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
tlmgr: updating /home/quinten/.TinyTeX/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
tlmgr update --list
tlmgr: package repository https://mirrors.evoluso.com/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
update:   texlive-scripts    [112k]: local:    66415, source:    66467
```

But the errors is still there. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this error?

---

**Please note**: I am currently using Linux.

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/909#issuecomment-1133556042) in a github issue shows the same error as you, and the following comment (by the same person) shows how to fix it (the whole thread is maybe helpful for you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it was probably fixed by installing Tex Live on Ubuntu via a terminal session like described [here](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/ubuntu/install-tex-live-texmaker). First, you should update the apt packages running this:

```
sudo apt update
```

To install Tex Live you should run the following:

```
sudo apt install texlive-full -y
```

After installing this, run `tinytex::install_tinytex()` in your Rstudio console and the error should be gone.

I also made sure that I have installed Quarto on my machine like described [here](https://docs.posit.co/resources/install-quarto/).