# Unable to knit cv awesomecv template in R vitae package

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, tinytex

When I try to knit the template awesomecv in the vitae package I get the following error:

```
< was unexpected at this time.
! LaTeX Error: File `enumitem.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Untitled2.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Untitled2.log for more info.
In addition: Warning message:
In system2("tlmgr", args, ...) :
  running command '"tlmgr" search --file --global "/enumitem.sty"' had status 255
Execution halted
```

Here is my sessionInfo():

```
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] fansi_1.0.4      utf8_1.2.3       digest_0.6.31    dplyr_1.1.1     
 [5] R6_2.5.1         lifecycle_1.0.3  magrittr_2.0.3   evaluate_0.20   
 [9] pillar_1.9.0     rlang_1.1.0      cli_3.4.1        rstudioapi_0.14 
[13] generics_0.1.3   vctrs_0.6.1      rmarkdown_2.20   tools_4.2.3     
[17] glue_1.6.2       xfun_0.37        yaml_2.3.7       fastmap_1.1.1   
[21] compiler_4.2.3   pkgconfig_2.0.3  htmltools_0.5.4  vitae_0.5.3     
[25] tidyselect_1.2.0 knitr_1.42       tibble_3.2.1
```

I have tried updating all packages and reinstalling `tinytex` but this hasn't worked.
Any tips gratefully received!

Comment: You could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75684829/error-your-texlive-version-is-not-updated-enough)? Maybe install texlive on your machine?